# Android version tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I see there is already a version-specific tag for Android 7 ([android-nougat](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-nougat)).

I have [this question, which relates to Android 8.1](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/52105/).

The help on the right suggests I should ask a question here to get a tag for that ([android-oreo](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-oreo)) if that makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

Do we really need a tag for each version of Android?

I understand the linked question as "`How to do X in <the latest Android version>`".

If Android 10 is released tomorrow, the asker would probably need to edit that question to bump up the version, right?

A "android-praline" tag only makes sense if the question is about a specific feature that existed only in android-praline, and not in android-oreo nor android-queijadinha. From what I see, the 6 questions in [android-nougat](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-nougat) are not really Nougat-specific so I would be in favour of merging that tag into [android](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android).

Comment: OK, perhaps that level of fragmentation may be more suitable for the Android stack exchange site.